# How to move data from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet, and need a macro.  In sheet1, I have several values of 7 numbers in a cell, For example, 1|2|3|4|5|6|7| up to 93|94|95|96|97|98|99|, which can be found on the columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, and I want for the example to extract all values that begin with the number 1, and put all the values onto worksheet 2 columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I,.
I've tried to extract the filter from the data tab using: sort and filter,,, filter,,,, filter by number,,,, and starting with,,,,.  Doing this, I apply the filter, but when I select the data values and take the selected, which does not work.

Thanks.

You understand me wrong, not so, will explain more fully,I like this 
column A 1|2|3|4|5|6|7| , 21|25|32|43|51|60|73|,  1|2|3|4|52|69|78| ,11|12|30|45|50|61|79| 
,3|5|70|74|75|77|79| , 1|22|33|44|50|63|75|, 1|22|33|44|50|63|75|................
column B   1|2|3|4|5|6|23| , 1|2|3|4|5|6|8|  , 1|2|3|4|5|6|9| , 1|2|3|4|5|6|10|   ,
11|21|31|40|52|61|70| ,  9|2|3|4|50|68|70|   ,  1|12|13|24|51|60|77| ,.........
column C   1|2|3|4|50|65|70|  , 2|5|7|9|10|16|37| ,5|8|9|14|15|26|67|,,,,,,,,,,,1|94|95|96|97|98|99|.
        In these columns I want to extract all values that begin with nr1 .....1|2|3|4|5|6|7|,,,1|90|91|92|93|94|95|  from sheet1 in the sheet2,
I mean these...
column A 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|  ,1|2|3|4|52|69|78|  ,1|22|33|44|50|63|75| ,1|20|31|43|55|60|71|
column B  1|2|3|4|5|6|23| , 1|2|3|4|5|6|8|  , 1|2|3|4|5|6|9| , 1|2|3|4|5|6|10| ,1|12|13|24|51|60|77| 
column C   1|2|3|4|50|65|70|  , 1|94|95|96|97|98|99|

Comment: If you split the single column into 7 columns using `Text to Columns` you should be able to sort and filter more easily.

Comment: So the first Cell `A1` contains the numbers `1|2|3|..|11|12|..|19|..|98|99` and you would like to move (/or copy?) the numbers that begin with 1 (so `1,11,12,...,18,19`) to columns in sheet 2 (for example `A1`=1, `B1`=11, `C1` =12). Is this correct?

Comment: @helpYou Please fix everything with the post that needs to be edited. Don't just remove one word without fixing all the other things that could be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the first Number in colum A needs to be one, then you want to copy colums A through I to sheet two then use:

```
Sub NumberOne()

Dim myvaraible As Integer
Dim CopyRow As Long, PasteRow As Long, LastRow As Long
CopyRow = 1
PasteRow = 1
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until CopyRow > LastRow
myVariable = Left(Range("A" & CopyRow).Value, 2)
If myVariable = "1" Then
Range("A" & CopyRow & ":I" & CopyRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & PasteRow & ":I" & PasteRow)
PasteRow = PasteRow + 1
End If
CopyRow = CopyRow + 1
Loop
'
End Sub
```

It will put them into new rows below each other. Any queries let me know

Comment: Will also copy cells beginning with 10,11,12,etc.  I think the OP wants the first number not the first digit.